# which one is true in a group

Tags: group-theory

Please offer me a hint  for determining if the following statements are true or false.

> a) If $H$ and $K$ ar normal and solvable in $G$ then $HK$ is normal and solvable.
>
> b) If $H$ and $K$ are normal and abelian subgroups in $G$, then $HK$ is normal and abelian.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hopefully you have no trouble showing that $HK$ has to be normal, if $H$ and $K$ are.

Hint for a): Use the fact that for $N\lhd G$, $G$ is solvable iff $G/N$ and $N$ are solvable, and look at the group $HK/H$ through the eyes of an isomorphism theorem.

Hint for b): the only concern is that elements of $H$ might not commute with elements of $K$. Try to find an example where this does not occur.

Comment: @BabakSorouh Good job at finding the example for b) :)

Answer (score 5):

Hint: For $(a)$, use the fact that $G$ is solvable if and only if for normal subgroups $N$, $N$ and $G/N$ are solvable.

For $(b)$, consider the quaternion group, as @BabakSorouh has pointed out.

Comment: Hmm, in $S_3$, $\sigma\tau\sigma^{-1}=\sigma^2\tau$, so I don't think that subgroup is normal...

Comment: @rschwieb: Unless $\sigma$ has order $2$.

Comment: @Clayton If it has order 2, the whole thing is abelian, and so $HK$ is solvable...

Comment: @rschwieb: Ach! you're correct; I made a mistake trying to go too quickly. I'll edit that to be correct.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: For b, consider: $$Q_8=\langle x,y\mid x^4=1,x^2=y^2,x^{-1}yx=y\rangle$$ and $H=\langle x\rangle$ and $K=\langle y\rangle$

Comment: +1 Nice hint...Hello! We're both "on" (@math.se), concurrently. Though I'm still groggy (overslept)!

Comment: This is the Klein $4$-group! $(xy)^2=xyxy=xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ so it is abelian...

Comment: @user1729: I was in a hurry. It was a shame.

Comment: (The Quaternion group has presentation $\langle i, j, k, -1; (-1)^2=1, i^2=j^2=k^2=ijk=-1\rangle$, and it *is* a valid counter-example. You can play with this presentation to get $\langle i, j; i^4, i^2j^2, (ij)^2\rangle$. There might be a neater $2$-generator presentation, I do not know.)

Comment: @user1729: Thanks sir for the Remark.

Comment: @rschwieb: It is a counter example for b. As you proved a is correct.

Comment: @BabakSorouh oh DUH :P I went and crossed up the two parts. Nevermind! I'm taking down the comment.

Comment: @user1729 It was just a dumb cognitive failure :) Thanks for being patient enough to read.

Comment: @rschwieb: Yes. I saw that $H=\{1,x,x^2, x^3\}$ and $K=\{1,y,y^2,y^3\}$ made a counterexample.